# Excel: Displaying only active members in Data Validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of drivers and the user can specify which are active and which are not. I want to try display the list of active drivers in a data validation only!

What I have done is the following:

[image]

I then created an item in the Name Manager with the following to try get those that are NOT blank(i.e only active), and then used a data validation to select all the results(which should only show active drivers) :

```
=OFFSET('Driver List'!$C$8:$C$1000,0,0,COUNTA('Driver List'!$C:$C)-COUNTBLANK('Driver List'!$C$8:$C$1000)-1,1)
```

This works if the LAST Driver active  is set to "No", but in the above example, "Roger Rabbit" does not show.

I am sure there must be an easy way to display only the active Drivers in a data validation??

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another approach to achieve what I was looking for. So I placed a button on the sheet where my drivers were to save only the active drivers(marked as Y) to another sheet. I then added this to my Named Manager(Name ranges) and then pointed my data validation(Drop down) to this named range.

The tricky part then came up that left spaces under the list each time a driver was marked between Y and N. So I manually changed the Name Ranges Range within code. Below is my code on the "Save Button" :

```
Sub Save_Active_Drivers()
    Dim iWB As Workbook
    Dim wsDL As Worksheet, wsADL As Worksheet
    Dim wsADLStartRow As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    DisableUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set MainWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDL = MainWorkbook.Sheets("Driver List")
    Set wsADL = MainWorkbook.Sheets("Active Drivers List")

    wsADL.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'wsADL.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    wsADL.Cells.Delete
    wsADLStartRow = 1

    For Each rw In wsDL.Rows
        If rw.row >= 8 Then
            If wsDL.Cells(rw.row, 23).Value <> "" Then
                If wsDL.Cells(rw.row, 24).Value <> "" Then
                        wsADL.Cells(wsADLStartRow, 1).Value = wsDL.Cells(rw.row, 24).Value
                        wsADLStartRow = wsADLStartRow + 1
                End If
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        End If


    Next rw



    LastRow = wsADL.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("DriversNames")
        .Name = "DriversNames"
        .RefersToR1C1 = "='Active Drivers List'!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C1"
        .Comment = ""
    End With

    wsADL.Select
    wsADL.Columns("A:A").Select
    wsADL.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wsADL.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("A1:A500"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With wsADL.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A500")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    wsADL.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete

    wsADL.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    wsDL.Select

    EnableUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Active Drivers Successfully Saved", vbOKOnly, "Active Drivers Saved!"
End Sub
```

This is a little custom to what I needed, but Ive struggled plenty to find any good help to do this... So I hope this helps someone in some way!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a hidden working column:  This would contain a formula using `INDEX` and `SMALL` or `AGGREGATE` to return *only* the Drivers that were active.  Then, you would point the `OFFSET` for your Named Range at that working column.

Something like:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$100)/--($B$1:$B$100="Y"),ROW()),1)
```

or

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,SMALL(ROW($A$1:$A$100)+1E+99*--($B$1:$B$100<>"Y"),ROW()),1)
```

**{EDIT}** *Since those formula will generate `#NUM!` or `#REF!` errors when you run out of items, you'll need to count the valid items with `=AGGREGATE(3,6,$C:$C)` or `=COUNTA($C:$C)+SUMPRODUCT(-ISERROR($C:$C))`*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I played around with the parts before your edit and it unfortunately did not work, so i needed to work on another approach. I ended up using VBA to populate another sheet, from which I then displayed in my data validation. Thanks in any case

Comment: @AxleWack Okay - in that case I would recommend you post that you ended up using VBA as an answer (possibly *with* the code that you used), and accept it, to 'close' the question :)

Comment: Done! Thanks for trying to help nevertheless.